# Where does this identity come from?

Tags: calculus

Where it come from 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } k^4 (-1)^k \log ^2(k)=\frac{-12 \pi  \zeta '(5)+12 \gamma  \pi  \zeta (5)-25 \pi  \zeta (5)+12 \pi  \zeta (5) \log (2)+12 \pi  \zeta (5) \log (\pi )}{8 \pi ^5}$$ Numerically seem diferent

Comment: Please do not use displaystyle in your question title. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/why-no-use-displaystyle-in-titles) for an explanation.

Comment: What is the source for this equation?
Why do you think, that this seems to work?  If I did not make any mistakes the left hand sides are 0,1,4 for $k=2,3,4$ and therefore different from $\Gamma(k)$.

Comment: gammtester prove again

Comment: @capea: could you define $\Gamma(a,b)$? If it's the Beta function, something doesn't make sense because $\Gamma(-1)=\infty$.

Comment: $\Gamma(a,b) = \int_b^{\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t} dt$ is the incomplete gamma function, you can prove the identity by applying binomial theorem to the integrands (assume one fix the sum of $n$ from $0$ to $k-1$)

Comment: The terms for $n=0,1,k\;$ are zero, because $\Gamma(2,-1)=0$ and ${{k-1}\choose k} =0.\;$ For $k=3$ the only non-zero term is for $n=2$. Therefore
$$\frac{2\Gamma(3,-1){2\choose 2}}{e\Gamma(3)}=\frac{2\times e \times 1}{e\times 2 }=1 \ne 2 =\Gamma(3)$$

Comment: Ah! Now I see that you have made the change $n \rightarrow n!$ in the numerator! But with this change the $n!$ cancels with $\Gamma(n+1)$ and the formula becomes simpler.

Comment: you are wright gammatester thanks for the observation

Comment: It can all be simplified to $$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{I_n}{n!\cdot(k-n-1)!}=e-e_{k-1}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1{n!}\qquad,\qquad I_n=\int_{-1}^0\frac{x^n}{e^x}dx$$